# How to get id instead of name with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need the name of the states to be displayed in the options, but I need to get the id instead of the name

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93njO.png)

The e.target.value only takes the name (a string), I need to get the id of the selected object or the entire object so that I can extract the id.

The id is needed to be able to send the object to the backend.

I already tried to use several methods of e.target, but I didn't get any result

Comment: Hello. Please don't use image to share your code snippet. You can use inline code (Ctrl+k) instead to put your code snippet into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<option id={states.id} value={states.id}>Volvo</option>
```

add value to options